# Multiple ReactDOM.render calls with shared router context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I got two React components rendered like this.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
    <Route path='/items' component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
      <Route path='/items/:id' component={ Details } />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And the second one, which is a sidebar.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Sidebar />,
  document.getElementById('sidebar')
);
```

I'd like to use the *Link* helper from react-router in the *Sidebar* component. However, I get the following error: "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Links rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.". Which makes sense, because the sidebar is not within the router context like the first seen above.

Is there a way to share the router context with the sidebar?

I'd like to change the sidebar layout based on the route (and access the router object in this.props properly) and use *Link* as it should be.

I don't want to work my way around hacky approaches like history.pushState, or parsing location.path to change the sidebar's layout according to the corresponding route of items.

Comment: Why is the `<Sidebar>` rendered separately? It should probably be within your `<App>` component. That would make things a lot more straightforward.

Comment: I know, but the current project structure does not allow me to use a single root component and let React handle the entire site. That would indeed be a lot easier as `<Sidebar>` is then part of the router context. Over time, when more of the site / app gets (re)written in React, we'll come closer to a general root element. Unfortunately, this is not yet the case today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just render your sidebar in its own `<Router>`. The important thing is that they share the same `history` instance (in this case, `browserHistory`).

When a `<Router>` mounts, it adds a listener to its `history` instance. When a `history` instance receives a new location, it notifies all of its listeners.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={Sidebar} />
  </Router>
) document.getElementById('sidebar')
```